# First encounter with State Diagrams

Tags: state-machines

I'm a beginner to all this and have had a little bit of trouble understanding how exactly these tables work outside their base examples.

I've made an attempt at drawing a diagram from a table that has 2 states and two outputs from 1 output and I'm mostly wanting confirmation that I am going about this correctly.

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks correct from a quick spot check.  Although I think there are 4 states (your question indicates you think there are only 2 states) and I think you mean "there are 2 outputs [X & Y] from 1 *input*".  Hope that helps

Comment: Okay thank you, I wasn't 100% sure on the b(t) and c(t) going together to form 1 state and the input and output being represented in the way it is, but thank you for the confirmation

Comment: Yeah, looks good.